# How ViewModel survives configuration change

Tags: android, mvvm, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I am trying to use ViewModel in my app. The question comes to my mind is How View Model survives configuration changes. I read number of blog posts saying that "

> It will create a **HolderFragment** to add to your activity or your
>   fragment, it's invisible, when the configuration changed, activity
>   destroyed, but holder fragment is still alive

and that make sense.But I tried to explore more on this and found out that in **support library  27.1.0+** they have removed the HolderFragment with  Description saying

> Deprecate ViewModelStores.of() and the **HolderFragment it relies on
>   as they are no longer needed** [link for android.googlesource](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/5122b0151b549a81b0c8cac9192b6713df0d81ab).

Now the question is How they are doing the same thing right now?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

ViewModels created with `ViewModelProviders.of()` method are stored in `ViewModelStore` hashmap, so the real question is how `ViewModelStore` is stored.

For activities, this logic is straightforward. `ViewModelStore` is stored using `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` method:

```
@Override
    @Nullable
    public final Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
        Object custom = onRetainCustomNonConfigurationInstance();

        ViewModelStore viewModelStore = mViewModelStore;
        if (viewModelStore == null) {
            // No one called getViewModelStore(), so see if there was an existing
            // ViewModelStore from our last NonConfigurationInstance
            NonConfigurationInstances nc =
                    (NonConfigurationInstances) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
            if (nc != null) {
                viewModelStore = nc.viewModelStore;
            }
        }

        if (viewModelStore == null && custom == null) {
            return null;
        }

        NonConfigurationInstances nci = new NonConfigurationInstances();
        nci.custom = custom;
        nci.viewModelStore = viewModelStore;
        return nci;
    }
```

For fragments, things are a bit more complicated. `FragmentManagerImpl` now has a field called `mNonConfig`:

`private FragmentManagerViewModel mNonConfig;`

which stores a hashmap of a Fragment's UUID and a `ViewModelStore`.

This `mNonConfig` field is initialized in `FragmentManagerImpl#attachController` method:

```
    public void attachController(@NonNull FragmentHostCallback host,
            @NonNull FragmentContainer container, @Nullable final Fragment parent) {
        if (mHost != null) throw new IllegalStateException("Already attached");
        mHost = host;
        mContainer = container;
        mParent = parent;
        if (mParent != null) {
            // Since the callback depends on us being the primary navigation fragment,
            // update our callback now that we have a parent so that we have the correct
            // state by default
            updateOnBackPressedCallbackEnabled();
        }
        // Set up the OnBackPressedCallback
        if (host instanceof OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner) {
            OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner dispatcherOwner = ((OnBackPressedDispatcherOwner) host);
            mOnBackPressedDispatcher = dispatcherOwner.getOnBackPressedDispatcher();
            LifecycleOwner owner = parent != null ? parent : dispatcherOwner;
            mOnBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(owner, mOnBackPressedCallback);
        }

        // Get the FragmentManagerViewModel
        if (parent != null) {
            mNonConfig = parent.mFragmentManager.getChildNonConfig(parent);
        } else if (host instanceof ViewModelStoreOwner) {
            ViewModelStore viewModelStore = ((ViewModelStoreOwner) host).getViewModelStore();
            mNonConfig = FragmentManagerViewModel.getInstance(viewModelStore);
        } else {
            mNonConfig = new FragmentManagerViewModel(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 17):

Basically, in order to retrieve a `ViewModel` in `Activity` one should call `ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(SomeViewModel.class)`. Now, if we look into `of` it looks like below:

```
public static ViewModelProvider of(@NonNull FragmentActivity activity,
        @Nullable Factory factory) {
    Application application = checkApplication(activity);
    if (factory == null) {
        factory = ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(application);
    }
    return new ViewModelProvider(activity.getViewModelStore(), factory);
}
```

So, the important part is this method - `activity.getViewModelStore()` because it returns a wrapper object (`HashMap` holder) for all of your `ViewModel` objects and if it can survive config changes so can all of your `ViewModel` objects:

```
public ViewModelStore getViewModelStore() {
    if (getApplication() == null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Your activity is not yet attached to the "
                + "Application instance. You can't request ViewModel before onCreate call.");
    }
    if (mViewModelStore == null) {
        NonConfigurationInstances nc =
                (NonConfigurationInstances) getLastNonConfigurationInstance();
        if (nc != null) {
            // Restore the ViewModelStore from NonConfigurationInstances
            mViewModelStore = nc.viewModelStore;
        }
        if (mViewModelStore == null) {
            mViewModelStore = new ViewModelStore();
        }
    }
    return mViewModelStore;
}
```

`mViewModelStore` will be either restored from `NonConfigurationInstances` or created from scratch. Pretty much, `NonConfigurationInstances` is the object that survives config changes and hence is used to store the `ViewModelStore`. That's why the same `ViewModelStore` object is returned after rotation - it's stored in the config change independent `NonConfigurationInstances`:

If you look into `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`, you will actually that your `ViewModelStore` is saved there:

```
public final Object onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() {
    ...
    NonConfigurationInstances nci = new NonConfigurationInstances();
    nci.custom = custom;
    nci.viewModelStore = viewModelStore;
    return nci;
}
```

Also, it will be cleared only if `onDestroy` for a non-config change reason is called:

```
...
    getLifecycle().addObserver(new LifecycleEventObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onStateChanged(@NonNull LifecycleOwner source,
                @NonNull Lifecycle.Event event) {
            if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY) {
                if (!isChangingConfigurations()) {
                    getViewModelStore().clear();
                }
            }
        }
    });
...
```

A similar trick is used for storing a `ViewModel` for a `Fragment`.

Comment: great answer, but isn't `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance` depricated in API 15?